# How can I use form files(.number/.exl/.scv) as Datasource for my iOS app

Tags: iphone, ios, database, ipad

I have some data stored in a number file, a table, how can I use it as the datasource for a tableView in iOS app

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a class to parse them, and set that class as the data source for your table view (using the methods in the UITableViewDataSource protocol).  Google tells me that .number files are bundles and the contents are simply compressed XML.  There are plenty of XML parsers available for iOS.